# How to Save a Modified Shelf in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

new to programming. I want to build a program that randomly selects an album from a dictionary and then permanently deletes it so I have the new, updated dictionary the next time I open my python script. However, when I run my code, the length of my dictionary always resets each time. If anyone can help, that'd be great. Here's the code:

```
import random
import shelve

albums = shelve.open('albums.db', 'n')
albums = {1: 'album1Name', 2: 'album2Name'...}

albumsSwitched = {y:x for x,y in albums.items()}

album = random.choice(albums)
albumKey = albumsSwitched.get(album)

del albums[albumKey]
```

Comment: How can you have the same dictionary if you permanently delete an album from it?

Comment: @RedCricket I meant to say the new, updated dictionary that is the same but has that one album removed from it.